# Porque en python empieza desde la columna 1 cuando pongo los nombres y no de la 0? como solucionarlo?

Tags: python, jupyter

Porque en python empieza desde la columna 1 cuando pongo los nombres y no de la 0? como solucionarlo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer en una de las 13 lineas anteriores hiciste algo como `data.set_index(0)`. Lo que puedes hacer para ver todas las columnas es `data.reset_index()`

Comment: mmm No, no es eso... quizas es popruqe es un archivo .txt que no se acomoda bien .. de loque fuere me gustaria solucionarlo @LucasDamian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que estas considerando al índice del `dataframe` como una columna y en realidad por una decisión de diseño en `pandas`, no lo es. Es decir, en tus datos, no existe la columna 0, la primer columna es la llamada `1` o luego `CT`. El indice es un dato particular que usa `pandas` en varias operaciones para mejorar la performance, pude ser un numérico automático o podrías transformar especialmente una columna o más de una en un índice. Un detalle, cuando ves los datos, si te fijas, el título del índice aparece una fila más abajo, eso justamente es una indicación de su naturaleza.

Si quisieras agregar una nueva columna a partir del índice, podrías hacer:

```
data['columna'] = data.index
```

O bien, si quieres directamente llevar el índice a columna

```
data = data.reset_index()
```